# How to communicate two processes using pipes

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes

I am using named pipes to communicate between two processes.

Writer.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    /* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "hi", sizeof("hi"));
    write(fd, "4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    write(fd, "hi2", sizeof("hi2"));
    write(fd, "5:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("5:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    write(fd, "6:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("6:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    write(fd, "7:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("6:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    write(fd, "8:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("6:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    write(fd, "9:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg", sizeof("6:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg"));
    sleep(5);
return 0;

}
```

Reader.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 2048

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];
    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
      int i;
      for( i =0; i < 6 ; i++)
      {
      int a = read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
       printf("buf has : %s with size = %d \n", buf,a);
       }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is like below:

```
buf has : hi with size = 3
buf has : 4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg with size = 124
buf has : 4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg with size = 0
buf has : 4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg with size = 0
buf has : 4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg with size = 0
buf has : 4:1.jpg,2.jpg;3.jpg with size = 0
```

I am wondering where the other strings have gone? Can some one please tell me what was wrong. I need the output to be like all the strings has to come one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

The `read` call returned all the data that you have written to the fifo. Your strings are 20 bytes long (19 bytes text and a terminating \0). Plus the "hi2" which is 4 bytes. And the second read returns size 124 (6*20+4).

Fifos contain a stream of data, not separate messages. You don't get one successful read for each successful write. You can get fewer or more reads than writes and it's up to you to invent a protocol that allows you to separate messages and buffering in the reader to collect and reassemble messages if they come in spread over multiple reads.

The reason your printf only prints the "first" message (there are no messages, just a stream of bytes) is because it's zero-terminated. So the other strings are in your buffer, but since you're printing the whole buffer as a string only the first string in it will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for incoming data - when `a == 0`, there is still no data in pipe. After `int a = ...` add this:

```
if ( a == 0 )
{
  i--; // repeat last iteration
  continue;
}
```

It is good idea to send number of lines first and then you will know how many text lines will arrive.